# 「embulk-filter-column」でカラムをコピーできない

Tags: embulk

embulkによりmysql内の特定カラムと同じ内容のカラムをコピーしたいのですが、
filter プラグインの「embulk-filter-column」がうまく機能してくれずコピーできません。

やりかたはこちらを参考にしました。
https://qiita.com/sonots/items/1acb9c53f0566bf78a9e

ログからも原因と解決策は抽出できませんでした。

何が間違ってると思われるでしょうか？
文法ミスの指摘お願い致します。

```
in:
  type: mysql
  host:  {{ env.HOST }}
  user: {{ env.USER }}
  password: {{ env.PASS }}
  database: {{ env.DB }}

filter:
  - type: column
    columns:
      - {name: DATA_COPY, src: DATE}

out:
  type: bigquery
  mode: replace
  auth_method: json_key
  json_keyfile: '{{ env.CREDENTIAL }}'
  path_prefix: tmp
  allow_quoted_newlines: 1 #
  file_ext: .csv.gz
  source_format: CSV
  project: {{ env.PROJECT }}
  dataset: {{ env.DATASET }}
  auto_create_table: true
  table: {{ env.TABLE }}
  formatter: {type: csv, charset: UTF-8, delimiter: ',', header_line: false}
  encoders:
  - {type: gzip}
```

IN情報

```
ID,DATE
1,2021-11-12
```

OUT情報

```
ID,DATE
1,2021-11-12
```

Answer (score 0):

indent miss

```
filters:
- type: column
  add_columns:
  - {name: DATA_COPY, src: DATE}
```